# Fetch users from local admin group on server

Tags: powershell

I tried below code script is running long and after that error Call Canceled. Servers are domain joined

```
function Get-LocalAdministrators {  
    param ($strcomputer)  
    $admins = Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser –computer $strcomputer   
    $admins = $admins |? {$_.groupcomponent –like '*"Administrators"'}  
    $admins | ForEach-Object {  
    $_.partcomponent –match ".+Domain\=(.+)\,Name\=(.+)$" > $nul  
    $matches[1].trim('"') + "\" + $matches[2].trim('"')  
    }  
}

#usage Get-LocalAdministrators "server name"
```

Comment: What Error do you get? Pls add it to your Question (not in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "server name" -Command {Get-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators'}
```

Comment: I tried this and getting error
"WinRM 
cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, 
that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception 
for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, 
the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers 
within the same local subnet" 

I also check WinRM Quickconfig on server 
1. Up and Running
2. remote access allowed

Comment: Ok, so you have to maybe fix the WinRM issues first, could be anything from firewall to authentication to kerberos... I would make some tests with invoke-command..

Answer (score 0):

You could also try ADSI with the WinNT provider:

```
$computerName = 'YourServerName'
$groupName    = 'Administrators'

$group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computerName/$groupName,group" 
($group.psbase.invoke("Members")) | ForEach-Object {([ADSI]$_).InvokeGet("Name")}
```